# spark-class: line 71...No such file or directory

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache-spark

I've installed Spark 2.1.1 on Ubuntu and no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to agree with the java path. When I run "spark-submit --version" or "spark-shell" I get the following error:

**/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory**

Now obviously the "/bin//bin/java" is problematic, but I'm not sure where to change the configuration. The spark-class file has the following lines:

```
if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
  RUNNER="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"
```

I was originally using a version of Spark meant for Hadoop 2.4 and when I changed it to "RUNNER="${JAVA_HOME}" it would either give me the error "[path] is a directory" or "[path] is not a directory." This was after also trying multiple path permutations in /etc/environment

What I now have in /etc/environment is:

**JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/"**

This is the current java setup that I have:

r**oot@ubuntu:~# update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java**

bashrc has the following:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark"
export PATH="$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin"
```

Can anyone advise: 1) What files I need to change and 2) how I need to change them? Thanks in advance.

spark-class file is in the link, just in case:

http://vaughn-s.net/hadoop/spark-class

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the /etc/environment file replace

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/
```

with

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

then execute

```
source /etc/environment
```

also `RUNNER="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"` should be kept as it is

Answer (score 1):

Windows Environment:

Open `Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables` to set `JAVA_HOME` path, and the most common mistake is setting the path to JAVA folder:

```
JAVA_HOME: Directory-Name:\java
```

rather than setting it to JDK folder

```
JAVA_HOME: Directory-Name:\jdk
```

This is how it worked for me.