# Spark-on-k8s:/opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /home/deploy/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I followed the instructions for running spark-on-k8s on https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#content

After submitting the example which is to launch Spark Pi in cluster mode, the pod met an error and I can't understand why it happened.

This is the command line:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://2-120:6443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=ethanzhang1997/spark:3.1.1 \
local:///path/to/examples.jar
```

Here is the error:
[error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roJyg.png)

I think this container should use java env in the image, but it tried to read the JAVA_HOME from my current computer.

Any help is important to me, with much thanks!

---

Now I temporarily solve this problem. I downloaded the corresponding version of jdk into spark dir and add the following lines to the Dockerfile which is to build the spark image:

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/deploy
ADD jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz /home/deploy/

ENV JAVA_HOME /home/deploy/jdk1.8.0_201
ENV JRE_HOME ${JAVA_HOME}/jre
ENV CLASSPATH .:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:${JRE_HOME}/lib
ENV PATH ${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

This makes sure that I have the same JAVA_HOME both in the image and host computer.

But there is still one thing I can't understand.The hadoop and spark env is also different between my host computer and image. Why this doesn't cause a problem? I noticed that there is a process to mount spark dir on the image, but how it works?

By the way, it seems that the offcial guidence on spark-on-kubernetes makes openjdk11 as default. But if user's JAVA_HOME is not set like this , there would be a problem, is it?

Comment: Hi @EthanZhang, welcome to StackOverflow. I have found very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834670/spark-class-line-71-no-such-file-or-directory. Is that a solution to your problem?

Comment: Thanks @Mikolaj Glodziak, but it's not the same question, his spark is installed in os but mine is in a k8s pod. And I think my JAVA_HOME setting is correct according to that question.

Comment: This error occurs when the path to `JAVA_HOME` is incorrectly set. It looks like you need to check the container image. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277631/change-java-home-in-docker/46277956) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657736/java-home-in-docker-container)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Mikolaj Glodziak. I solve this problem temporarily. And I add the solution below my question description. But I am not fully understand the mechanism behind this.

Comment: Running something in a container keeps it separate from the rest of the environment. If you need any variables in the container - they must be in the container image. "The hadoop and spark env is also different between my host computer and image." In your case, you are only interested in the variable in the container image.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue recently & did a bit of testing to understand this behaviour. Below are my findings.

If there exists an
`export JAVA_HOME=\path\to\java` command in spark-env.sh in the launch machine's (machine from which spark-submit to k8 is happening) $SPARK_HOME/conf folder, then that exact value is used as java home on both the launch machine, as well as inside the docker container (even if you set JAVA_HOME environment variable in your container). Tried multiple options to override the spark-env value inside the docker container, but to no avail.

However, if you remove the JAVA_HOME export command from the spark-env.sh, then the JAVA_HOME is taken from bash_profile (or if exported otherwise) in both the launch machine & the docker container.